# -[ValidatorWebView .cxx_destruct] crash ios

Tags: ios, uiwebview, crash, google-fabric

i am getting lots of crashes related to : -[ValidatorWebView .cxx_destruct]
only thing i can assume from logs is: it happens on app launch.
need some help to review more about crash logs:

here are crash logs:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libdispatch.dylib              0x18a1c2974 _dispatch_semaphore_dispose + 72
1  libdispatch.dylib              0x18a1c26ec _dispatch_dispose + 56
2  <Appname>                       0x1003cb9ac -[ValidatorWebView .cxx_destruct] + 4298996140
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x189d66f00 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x189d74334 objc_destructInstance + 92
5  libobjc.A.dylib                0x189d74398 object_dispose + 28
6  UIKit                          0x1917d3470 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 156
7  UIKit                          0x19142ec5c -[UIView dealloc] + 1636
8  UIKit                          0x19164ad28 -[UIWebView dealloc] + 540
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x189d86134 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 836
10 CoreFoundation                 0x18b1e2b28 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18b2b5aa4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
12 CoreFoundation                 0x18b2b57a8 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 856
13 CoreFoundation                 0x18b2b5068 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 244
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18b2b2c8c __CFRunLoopRun + 1484
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18b1e2da4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
16 GraphicsServices               0x18cc4c074 GSEventRunModal + 100
17 UIKit                          0x191496058 UIApplicationMain + 208
18 <Appname>                        0x1000efb80 main (main.m:14)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x18a1f159c start + 4
```

Comment: Is this coming from a `UIWebView` that you created? Can you give any more context or code?

Comment: thanks for reply, i haven't created any webview, but i am using many sdks , which are initializing during app launch. i am not able to replicate this crash, but i saw above crash in fabric logs.

Comment: @Matrix it seems like object deallocs at wrong time

Comment: yeah, that we can say from: cxx_destruct.

Comment: but i am not using anything like: ValidatorWebView in client app, so it looks like from sdks. but again, we have many sdks, so difficult to figure out from which sdk. 

is there any command using which i can search a word inside *.a or *.frameworks ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can using `otool`. Never used it myself, but found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412268/find-source-of-class-symbols-in-binary